# How to link entities added to DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

### DISCLAIMER

**I'm not trying to refresh anything FROM or TO database.

The answer I'm looking for should be found into the context, in memory.**

### ABSTRACT

I'm facing a strange EF behaviour (I think it's not an actual bug), it seems the "same" conceptual operation works in 2 different ways depending by the preconditions.
Fortunately the case is simple and reproducible.
The model consists in a pair of related tables; when I add one table directly to its Context's DbSets (it doesn't matter which side of the relationship) if the other table of the pair is "already loaded" sometimes the link among the two is established and sometimes not, it depends if the other table (the table that the Context already knows) is "Read_from_DB" or "Added".

I try to better describe the issue with the 2 scenario:

### DB MODEL

The DB Model is a simple master / details:

1. **`T_PARENTS`** (with a `Collection<T_CHILDREN>`)
2. **`T_CHILDREN`** (with a `Reference<T_PARENTS>`)

### SCENARIO 1

1. In **DB** we have:

   - 1 row in `T_PARENTS` with key "xyz"
   - 0 rows in `T_CHILDREN`
2. In **c#** we load all the data with:

   - `ctx.T_PARENTS.ToList();` (1 row loaded)
   - `ctx.T_CHILDREN.ToList();` (0 rows loaded)
   - `var existing_parent = ctx.T_PARENTS.First();`
3. at this point `existing_parent` has a collection of `T_CHILDREN` with 0 rows.
4. In **c#** we add a new `T_CHILDREN` with:

   - `var new_child = new T_CHILDREN() {parent_key = "xyz"};`
   - `ctx.T_CHILDREN.Add(new_child);`
5. Here the **Context made its magic** and in the object **`existing_parent`** we can find the **`Collection<T_CHILDREN>`** now having 1 row (the row just added).

### SCENARIO 2

1. In **DB** we have:

   - 0 row in `T_PARENTS`
   - 0 rows in `T_CHILDREN`
2. In **c#** we load all the data with:

   - `ctx.T_PARENTS.ToList();` (0 row loaded)
   - `ctx.T_CHILDREN.ToList();` (0 rows loaded)
3. In **c#** we add a new `T_PARENTS` with:

   - `var new_parent = new T_PARENTS() {key = "xyz"};`
   - `ctx.T_PARENTS.Add(new_parent);`
4. In **c#** we add a new `T_CHILDREN` with:

   - `var new_child = new T_CHILDREN() {parent_key = "xyz"};`
   - `ctx.T_CHILDREN.Add(new_child);`
5. Here the **Context didn't make any magic** and the object **`new_parent`** still has the  **`Collection<T_CHILDREN>`** with 0 rows (we can't find the new_children just added to the context).

### Questions are:

- Why?
- **Is there any function to invoke against the Context to "refresh" the Collections & References of all the Entities attached to the Context?** (*...and No, `ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` doesn't work :-)*)

Thanks again guys!
mM

Comment: I found out a viable workaround (but this is not the answer I was looking for) .  



`var objCtxDelivery = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctxDelivery).ObjectContext;`
`objCtxDelivery.AcceptAllChanges();`

Answer (score 0):

This is all about the entity state with the context. The most important method to use here is [`DbContext.Entry(object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696238%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) The [`EntityEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) returned will give you the [`EntityState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.entitystate%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

In the first scenario, `existing_parent` is already a tracked object, in the second it is most likely detached, until you `SaveChanges`, or explicitly set the `State` of the `EntityEntry` to `EntityState.Added`.

*More on Why*: In the second scenario, you added an object to a collection, but did not actually tell the context itself to do anything with it. By setting the information on the `EntityEntry`, you are explicitly telling the context "Track This Object"

Comment: hi Eris, first of all thanks for the theoretical clarification! Anyway, even in the second scenario I add the `new_parent` using the `ctx.T_PARENTS.Add(new_parent);` and this function sets automatically the State to Added and makes the Context aware of this entity, so the reason should be different.